# how do I test toggle theme button using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the button which toggles the theme using material UI. How can I do it using Jest and enzyme. I am a newbie in testing and hence don't know much about it. Pardon for it.

Please don't bother about any functionality. The only thing I need is the testing code using **Jest** and **Enzyme**.

If you provide me the resource also that would be a great help.

**Header.js**

```js
<MenuItem onClick={props.toggleTheme} data-testId="header-toggleTheme" >
                                {props.theme === 'light' ? (
                                    <Brightness2Icon style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                                ) : (
                                    <Brightness7Icon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                                )}
                            </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass toggleTheme and theme as props to your component in [shallow rendering](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) or [mount](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html).

And then test toggleTheme is called MenuItem click and also check props value changes or not.

Sample Test code

```
describe("Test of Header", () => {
    let component, props;
    beforeEach(() => {
        component = mount(<Header />);
    });

   it("Test toggle theme", () => {
        let theme = "light";
        let toggleTheme =  jest.fn(() => {
            let nextTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
            component.setProps({...props, theme: nextTheme});
        });
        props = {
            toggleTheme,
            theme,
        }
        component.setProps({...props});
        expect(component.props().theme).toEqual("light");
        component.find(MenuItem).simulate("click");
        expect(component.toggleTheme).toBeCalled();
        expect(component.props().theme).toEqual("dark");
   });
});
```

**Note:** Please import the respective module and if changes required then please change accordingly.

Comment: can you write the test for it, because I read many articles but didn't get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KunalKumar, I have updated the answer and add sample code